# Bootstrap tabs showing on top even after using tabs-right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a simple navbar at the right and pane on the left. Like they have showed in their [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navs) (section - Tabs on the right).

But the tabs are coming on the top only. Here's the [JsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b6zvmfmr/)

Am i doing anything wrong? Are `tabs-right` deprecated in new version of bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bootstrap version you are using is `Bootstrap v3.3.5`.

The documentation you are referring to is `Bootstrap v2.0.0`.

Use the right version as your code is right.

**Snippet**

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabbable tabs-right">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#rA" data-toggle="tab">Section 1</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#rB" data-toggle="tab">Section 2</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="#rC" data-toggle="tab">Section 3</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="rA">
      <p>I'm in Section A.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="rB">
      <p>Howdy, I'm in Section B.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="rC">
      <p>What up girl, this is Section C.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b6zvmfmr/1/**

Comment: Is this deprecated in `v3.3.5`

Comment: Yup. It seems to be deprecated!